# Including Java bean from another project in the same application

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, javabeans, jsp-tags, jdeveloper

I have A jdeveloper J2EE application, it contains 2 projects "Model" and "ViewController", I want to use the ( java bean class"Calculate" from The package"model" which is in the project "Model" )  inside a JSP page which  in the project ViewController, i tried the useBean action tag  but it didn't work, do anyone know how i could use it ?

Comment: Post the jsp and the stack-trace error please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the project properties of the view project, under "Dependencies" set a dependency on the model project.